# Excel on 2 worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have done this before but have forgotten the steps.

Worksheet 1:

Data: all `Customers`, with their sales entries for the month, with repeat on different days.

Worksheet 2:

I have classified the `Customers` under `Group` as: Wholesale, Retails, Cash. I manually key that in beside the customers.

I need this Group because I do a Pivot table; I can know the customer is either Wholesale, Retails, or Cash.

In Worksheet 1, I create a new column: `Group`.  In this column, I need to enter a formula that matches the  `Customers` in Worksheet 1 and Worksheet 2 and shows the Group from Worksheet 2.

Please assist me.

Comment: Can you add your sheet with dummy data as example

Answer (score 0):

You need to combined INDEX() and MATCH() while index() identifies the element from an array, match() helps you in identifying the row to be replicated

So if you have say a row in Sheet2

```
ColumnA           ColumnB
Name              Type
Customer1         Retail
Customer2         Cash
Customer3         Wholesale
```

And this is in row number 1

and in Sheet1 you have the same customer (Say Customer3) in cell A3 then you should enter

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B1:B3,MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!A1:A3,0))
```